# Передать номер потока каждому потоку

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, pthread

Хочу передавать функции в качестве параметра номер потока, которому она принадлежит. Можно ли делать это так?

```
for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM; ++i) {
    pthread_create(&threads_arr[i], NULL, foo, &i);
}
```

Или указатель на номер должен жить всё время жития потока и поэтому надо сделать отдельный массив `0,1,...,THREAD_NUM-1`? Или есть другие способы?

Comment: можно, нет не обязательно (можно сразу разыменовать и сохранить), есть

Comment: @goldstar_labs почему можно? сколько живут переменные цикла?

Comment: @AlexF что значит `int casted to void*`? `(void*) i`? Разве это не будут адреса `0x0, 0x1` и т.д.?

Comment: @brr в том то и дело - просто кастуете к int в функции (никакого разыменовывания)

Comment: переменные цикла живут в области видимости цикла. при создании потока вы получаете адрес переменной цикла, разыменовываете и сохраняете в локальную переменную потока

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch логично) но похоже на костыль, всё таки там ожидается корректный адрес

Comment: @goldstar_labs а вы уверены, что поток успеет разыменовать до того, как переменная уйдет из области видимости и адрес станет невалидным?

Comment: @brr да, костыль, но раз у вас указан с++, то почему бы не использовать стандартные потоки? Там с этим гораздо проще

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch согласен, но уже используются `pthreads` в проекте, вот осваиваю

Comment: не уверен, что-то я несу фигню)